# Как сверстать такую кнопку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, веб-программирование, button

Как сверстать такую кнопку ?

На **:hover** должна отзываться вся кнопка.

```html
<button>default</button>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем у вас проблема? Что пробовали? Какие проблемы возникли в процессе реализации?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 75px 10px 45px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
button:after {
  content: '›';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
}
button:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
button:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button>default</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Единственное, что элементу :after тоже стоило бы transition добавить

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 75px 10px 45px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
button:after {
  content: '›';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
transition: 0.3s;
}
button:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
button:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button>default</button>
```

Comment: Зачем? Он ведь теперь с задержкой изменяется.

Comment: Но до этого с задержкой изменялось все, кроме элемента after, так кусочно было лучше? .-.